# How to stop divs moving out of their parent div

Tags: html, css, parent

I have read previous answers on how to stop divs moving with wrappers and parent divs but I have had no luck on this matter. I have 5 images, each in its own div, all inside of a parent div. when the browser's width is shortened the images go underneath eachother.

html: 
    
        
            
            
            
            
            
        
        
            image description
            image description
            image description
            image description
            image description

CSS:

```
#mid {
 min-width: 1080px;
 height: 350px;
 background-color: #a3a3a3;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 25px; 
}

.imagebox {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 180px;
 width: 300px;
 border: 2px solid #42a7f0;
 margin-top: 30px;
}

.image-inbox {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.image-inbox:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
 }

#mid1 {
 height: 220px;
 min-width: 1080px;
}

.description {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100px;
 width: 300px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 text-align: left;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: #005fa3;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Having the images collapse like that is usually good practice for mobile viewers. That being said, what would you like it to do instead?

Comment: Idealy I would prefer them to all stay on the same line and just be smaller, i've thought about using percentages for this but had no luck. 
when they collapse they go behind the descriptions of the first three images, if this didn't happen it would be okay... Thank you for the reply